# Why Fastboot boot Twrprecovery.img hangs loads after 3-4 tries

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, bootloader

**Question :- Why Fastboot boot Twrprecovery.img hangs loads after 3-4 tries?**

I for original backup of Nandroid from twrp  recovery from PC computers I load twrp recovery image in bootloader fastboot mode through command fastboot boot twrprexovery.img but as I run command  the mobile white screen goes to blank black and in pc continuously prompts multiple drives   a dialogue box  to format multiple drives loaded created on twrp mtp (e,f,g,h,j,k) mounted after fastboot boot twrprecovery command. What I think happened twrp crating multiple mtp drives and closing I am have cancel multiple dialogue boxes in computer windows 10.

**Other commands used in sequence**

```
Adb devices
Adb reboot bootloader
Fastboot devices
Fastboot boot twrprecovery.img
```

But after rebooting reconnecting to different usb sockets mobile and trying 2-3 times this  fastboot boot twrprecovery.img it finally display and load twrp image and display twrp menu.. and I took backup and recovery  all went succesful....it means twrp  image is right  and not corrupted and working fine...and for same device

The problem is why it's loading after 2-3 attempt on same usb port same drivers same cable  it happened many time not one time.

Now I am asking as I want to **install flash twrprexovery.img**  to  recovery partition and wooried that is it problem to image or any thing with  it don't create problem after installing flashing .. how should I install twrp recovery  which command is safe (fastboot flash recovery twrp.img)
Should I install as twrp recovery can be loaded and used with pc without installing but will not run through mobile.

Comment: yes it's safe just flash it. But consider dm-verity should be disabled (newer android versions only)